# Problem with fake multiple vertical touch events at once - OpenJDK 11.0.2

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

Several times a day I observe multiple touch events at once, whereas I touch only with one finger to one place.

These touches are always vertical = almost the same X coordination, but the large area in Y coordination. I’m using resolution 1920x1080.

I’ve tried 2 different touch monitors, but the same behaviour – both iiyama T2235MSC-B1. I’ve written C++ touch application to check my touch screen, but it’s perfectly okay, no this behaviour in C++. Only in Java FX. I’m using OpenJDK 11.0.2 and Windows 10.

Every time this happens only when I touch the screen. Is there any cache for touch events in JavaFX, which is not properly cleaned? Have you observed this as well? What can I do? This is a showstopper for my whole app in production.

Problem starts at

```
[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.740+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:193) - TOUCH_PRESSED target button - ID fastB1, classes button keyboardBtn fastB1Style

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.740+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:214) - - touchEvent - setID = 1, touchPoint count = 1, point = [1163.0, 77.0]

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.740+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1163.0, 77.0], state = PRESSED

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.741+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:193) - TOUCH_PRESSED target button - ID fastB2, classes button keyboardBtn fastB2Style

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.741+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:214) - - touchEvent - setID = 2, touchPoint count = 2, point = [1153.0, 148.0]

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.741+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1163.0, 77.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.741+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1153.0, 148.0], state = PRESSED
```

…

Many other events come one by one till approx 8 stationary events at one:

```
[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.745+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1163.0, 77.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.745+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1153.0, 148.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.745+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1163.0, 239.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.746+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1160.0, 314.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.746+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1159.0, 413.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.746+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1160.0, 482.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.746+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1154.0, 539.0], state = PRESSED

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.746+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:193) - TOUCH_PRESSED target button - ID null, classes button keyboardBtn

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.746+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:214) - - touchEvent - setID = 8, touchPoint count = 8, point = [1150.0, 975.0]

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.746+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1163.0, 77.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.746+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1153.0, 148.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.746+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1163.0, 239.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.747+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1160.0, 314.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.747+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1159.0, 413.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.747+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1160.0, 482.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.747+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1154.0, 539.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.747+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1150.0, 975.0], state = PRESSED

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.806+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:193) - TOUCH_RELEASED target button - ID fastB1, classes button keyboardBtn fastB1Style

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.807+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:214) - - touchEvent - setID = 18, touchPoint count = 8, point = [1163.0, 77.0]

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.807+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1163.0, 77.0], state = RELEASED

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.807+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1153.0, 148.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.807+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1163.0, 239.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.807+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1160.0, 314.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.807+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1159.0, 413.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.807+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1160.0, 482.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.807+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1154.0, 539.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.807+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1150.0, 975.0], state = STATIONARY
```

…

and then decreasing one by one begins:

```
[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.812+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:197) - TOUCH_RELEASED No target/parent button/label - target is javafx.scene.control.TextField

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.812+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:214) - - touchEvent - setID = 23, touchPoint count = 3, point = [1160.0, 482.0]

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.813+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1160.0, 482.0], state = RELEASED

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.813+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1154.0, 539.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.813+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1150.0, 975.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.813+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:193) - TOUCH_RELEASED target button - ID null, classes button lightGreen2 keyboardBtn

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.813+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:214) - - touchEvent - setID = 24, touchPoint count = 2, point = [1154.0, 539.0]

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.813+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1154.0, 539.0], state = RELEASED

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.813+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1150.0, 975.0], state = STATIONARY

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.840+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:193) - TOUCH_RELEASED target button - ID null, classes button keyboardBtn

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.841+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:214) - - touchEvent - setID = 30, touchPoint count = 1, point = [1151.0, 975.0]

[DEBUG] 2019-03-01T12:03:38.841+01:00 [JavaFX Application Thread] (BaseScene.java:216) - --> point: [1151.0, 975.0], state = RELEASED
```

EDIT:

I would like to add, that I’m using this code to bind EventHandler:

```
getScene().setOnTouchPressed(this);
getScene().setOnTouchReleased(this);
```

Then this method is called:

```
@Override
public void handle(InputEvent e) {
    handleEvent(e);
}
private void handleEvent(InputEvent e) {…}
```

Touch point are iterated (for logging) this way:

```
if (e instanceof TouchEvent) {
TouchEvent te = ((TouchEvent) e);
INPUT_EVENTS_LOGGER.debug("- touchEvent - setID = " + te.getEventSetId() + ", touchPoint count = " + te.getTouchCount() + ", point = [" + te.getTouchPoint().getScreenX() + ", " + te.getTouchPoint().getScreenY() + "]");
for (TouchPoint tp : te.getTouchPoints()) {
INPUT_EVENTS_LOGGER.debug("--> point: [" + tp.getScreenX() + ", " + tp.getScreenY() + "], state = " + tp.getState().name());
}
}
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue, not only the logs/errors. You might also want to consider submitting a bug report if the problem isn't with your own code (and the bug isn't already reported).

Comment: I've added my code, I think there isn't any error in it. Because touch point error aren't all the time but only a few every day, I'm not sure where is the error. I've also sent this to OpenJavaFX mailing list.